# Breadcrumbs in Drupal Bootstrap is not updating when the menu link title is changed

Tags: breadcrumbs

we are using Drupal 7 and are having a problem with the drupal-bootstrap module. When we change the "Menu link title" to a new string the breadcrumb text string is not updated

- We are running the latest version of the drupal-bootstrap module
- I've tried clearing the cache inside of Drupal (configuration - development - performance - caches - clear all caches)
- I've also cleared the browser cache and tried to load the page on two different computers

Does anyone know what else we could try here or what the problem is? I'd prefer to stay away from the PHP code if possible

One option would be to just remove the page and create a new one with the new "Menu link title"

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: Maybe there is another menu link somewhere / in the database, which still has the old title?

Comment: Also, are you sure that those breadcrumb titles are coming from menu links? Can you reproduce this for other pages? And what happens if you change the theme?

Comment: @donquixote Thank you for the questions, can't answer all of them at the moment but i have been able to reproduce the problem yes